# Entity framework: string property is empty after calling SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I got a mapped entity named User - with username and pass, the pk is the username.

When saving a new user, the username for some reason becomes an empty string.

Here is a code sample:

```
var newUser = new User() {Username = model.UserName, Password = hashedPassword};

_db.Users.AddObject(newUser);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

In debug view I see user name is not empty before save and after save it's empty. Whats wrong with me?

Comment: What is "model" in your code? I'm assuming a User object, but it would be helpful to see more code.

Comment: Is your data saved correctly after calling `SaveChanges`?

Comment: How is your `UserName` property configured in your model? The behavior looks like it has `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity` or `Computed`. Btw. it is better to use separate integer column as a key.

Comment: My StoreGenerationPattern is set to none.

Answer (score 0):

The dev server decided to ignore my reset, so I needed to reset it again and it's fine.